# ViewPager inside a Fragment shows blank Xamarin Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android, android-viewpager, fragment

I am developing a Xamarin Android application. I have created a drawer layout which loads fragments in a frame layout. In one fragment I want to show view pager with a tab layout. But fragment doesn't show anything and stays blank.

Here is the code for fragment containing ViewPager.

```
public class HomeFeedFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
{
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    ICharSequence[] titles = CharSequence.ArrayFromStringArray(new string[] 
    { "Business", "Activity", "Place", "Tracking" });
    Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment[] fragments;
    Adapters.ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your fragment here
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout_feed_tabs, container, false);
        tabLayout = view.FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tabLayout);
        viewPager = view.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewPager);

        fragments = new Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment[]
        {
            new FeedItemsFragment(Service.DbService.FeedItems.Where(p => p.PostType == PostType.Business.ToString()).ToList()),
            new FeedItemsFragment(Service.DbService.FeedItems.Where(p => p.PostType == PostType.Activity.ToString()).ToList()),
            new FeedItemsFragment(Service.DbService.FeedItems.Where(p => p.PostType == PostType.Place.ToString()).ToList()),
        };
        adapter = new Adapters.ViewPagerAdapter(ChildFragmentManager, fragments, titles);
        viewPager.Adapter = adapter;
        tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        return base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Adapter to bind fragments is shown below:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter : Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment[] fragments;
    ICharSequence[] titles;
    public ViewPagerAdapter(Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fm, Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment[] fragments,
        ICharSequence[] titles) : base(fm)
    {
        this.fragments = fragments;
        this.titles = titles;
    }

    public override int Count => fragments.Length;

    public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem(int position)
    {
        return fragments[position];
    }

    public override ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
    {
        return titles[position];
    }
}
```

I am new to Xamarin.

Comment: Paste you code here, pictures doesn't load correctly for some people.

Comment: Changed images with code.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace line

```
return view;
```

with

```
return base.OnCreateView(( inflater,  container, savedInstanceState));
```

Comment: I changed based.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState); with view and it worked just perfectly fine.